# Web Service method only reads the last object in a list

Tags: c#, wcf

I have to make a WCF service app, that has some static information stored in Lists, and methods for querying that information. The service is hosted in a console app and will later be turned into a real database with entity framework.

I have the following classes `Doctor`, `Patient`, `UserAccount` and an `IService1` interface, with methods that are meant to be used by those classes.

I have 3 issues so far

1. The login method always returns false.
2. The method `DoctorByID`, only returns the last `Doctor` object that has been created
3. The method `PatientByID` is the same as in the `DoctorByID` method.

The cs files are in the same project, the project builds and web services are all updated. When I put the Lists on watch, they get filled up as expected. I dont know where it all goes wrong.

```cs
//The interface and the classes 
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1 
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    string DoctorById(string ID);
    [OperationContract]
    bool Login(string name, string ID)
} 

[DataContract]
public class Doctor 
{ 
    [DataMember]
    public static List<Doctor> ListOfDoctors = new List<Doctor>();
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; } 
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public Doctor(string name, string lastName, string id, DateTime dateOfBirth) 
    {
        Name = name;
        LastName = lastName;
        ID = id;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        //Adds the created doctors to the list
        ListOfDoctors.Add(this);
    }
}
//The DataContracts for the patients and UserAccounts look almost the same.

//Object instantiation and method implemenation

public class Service1: IService1 
{
    public static Doctor doctor1 = new Doctor("Simon", "Doe", "doc1", new DateTime(1996, 08, 08));
    public static Doctor doctor2 = new Doctor("John", "Doe", "doc2", new DateTime(1966, 12, 10));
    public static Doctor doctor3 = new Doctor("Mike", "Ray", "doc3", new DateTime(1990, 02, 18));

    public static UserAccount user1 = new UserAccount("Edd", "password", true);
    public static UserAccount user2 = new UserAccount("Tony", "password", true);
    public static UserAccount user3 = new UserAccount("John", "1234", false);

    //METHOD FROM ISSUE NO.1
    public bool Login(string userName, string pass) 
    {
        bool answer = "";
        foreach(UserAccount acc in UserAccount.ListOfUsers) 
        {
            if (acc.UserName == userName && acc.Password == pass) 
            {
                if (acc.AdminRights == true) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have Admin Rights");
                    answer = true;
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("You do not have Admin rights");
                answer = false;
            }
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Account does not exist");
        answer = false;
    }
    return answer ;
}

//METHOD FROM ISSUE NO.2
public string PatientById(string ID) 
{
    string answer = "";
    foreach(Patient p in Patient.ListOfPatients) 
    {
        if (p.ID == ID) 
        {
            answer = "patient ID :" + p.ID + " Name: " + p.name + "  LastName: " + p.lastName;
        }
        else 
        {
            answer = "The patient with this ID does not exist";
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Since I cant post pictures here, i put up the screenshots on img. It takes a couple of seconds to load them

Here are the links to the outputs that i got throught the Wcf test client:

1. https://ibb.co/h1ghZ7y
   -The login function returns `false`, despite the object having a bool value of true.
2. https://ibb.co/BqJWqQC
   -The `DoctorByID` function returns "The doctor ID doesnt exist", but the object with that `ID` is on the list.
3. https://ibb.co/SQkJRcy
   -The `DoctorByID` function returns data about the object, but only does so when I put the LAST OBJECT in the list as the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm trying to find a start.

```
//METHOD FROM ISSUE NO.1
public bool Login(string userName, string pass)
{
 bool answer="";
 foreach(UserAccount acc in UserAccount.ListOfUsers)
  {
   if(acc.UserName==userName && acc.Password == pass)
   { 
     if(acc.AdminRights==true)
     {
      Console.WriteLine("You have Admin Rights");
      answer=true;
     }
     else
     Console.WriteLine("You do not have Admin rights");
     answer= false;
     }
   }
  else
  Console.WriteLine("Account does not exist");
  answer= false;
 }
 answer odgovor;
}
```

This thing would never compile. Why would you initiate a boolean variable with `""`? And what is `answer odgovor`? And why is your method not returning anything?

However the reason because the method returns `false` is because you have two places like this:

```
  if
  {
    ...
  }
  else
  Console.WriteLine("Account does not exist");
  answer= false;
```

... which translates to ...

```
  if
  {
    ...
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Account does not exist");
  }
  answer= false;
```

... because you left out the `{}` after `else`. So the code will always reach `answer = false`, whether or not the login was successful or not.

You could have found this easily by stepping through the code with the debugger.

---

The second one ... well ...

```
//METHOD FROM ISSUE NO.2
public string PatientById(string ID)
{
    string answer= "";
    foreach(Patient p in Patient.ListOfPatients)
    {
        if (p.ID == ID)
        {
            answer = "patient ID :" + p.ID + " Name: " + p.name + "  LastName: " +                             p.lastName; 
        }
        else
        {
            answer = "The patient with this ID does not exist";
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

What's happening here is that you might find many patients by a given id but even if you did, you'll always overwrite the prior strings with a new one. That's the reason why only the last match will be returned.

Comment: Ill fix the first issue, i had to translate the code to english, thus made some errors in the process. The original code compiles. Also thanks for the second method answer, youre right. I Wrote a dumb method there